# Inspect Element in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, inspect

How do we inspect element in android studio.

The eclipse counterpart is `Ctrl+Shift+I`(after selecting a variable or expression, press `Ctrl+Shift+I` ).
Couldn't find this on the internet, please help!

Comment: I want to know how do it too.

Comment: Did you find any answer?

Answer (score 2):

In Mac OSX, you can use 
<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, sadly I use Windows :). Will check if Ctrl +Alt +F8 does the trick.