# How to inspect element in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to achieve the similar experience as Chrome F12 in Android App Debugging, i.e., get the resource ids of certain objects, even merrier, see their styles and event handlers,

Just tried this one: 
[Inspect Element in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668834/inspect-element-in-android-studio)

But it didn't work, because I don't have enough rep points I cannot comment on that answer, so I have to post my question here:

- Is it possible to inspect element in Android Studio?
- What's that answer is about? Is it possible to do it in PC?

Comment: Are you inspecting your own app? The just open an XML layout and click the Design Tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the question you linked is about inspection code elements, not view elements.

---

You can inspect the view hierarchy using the Android Device Monitor. Just  select **Hierarchy View** from the perspectives. Source: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html

---

As of Android Studio 3.1 or later, Hierarchy Viewer is deprecated. You should instead use Layout Inspector to inspect your app's view hierarchy at runtime. View -> Tool Windows -> Layout Inspector.

Comment: Thank you, it's not exactly F12, i.e., providing on-the-scene capturing,  but kind of providing layout breakd-down and component ids.

Comment: Android studio does also provide screen capturing and recording http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html#screenCap

Comment: Tools > Layout Inspector is greyed out for me.
What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

For the inspect element in android studio you can use "Evaluate expression".
Just select the piece of expression you want to inspect and right click on it and select Evaluate Expression. Have a look at the image below:

[image]

This will open you a new floating window and you can see what is the value of that expression during while debugging.